# access array within array and map values

Tags: ruby, arrays, dictionary

I am reading from a CSV file with an array that becomes

```
parse = [["742", "Rewards", "0.309", "0.249", "0.0195", "0.1"], ["742", "Reg (DB)", "0.165", "0.194", "0.0005", "0.21"]]
```

I am trying to access the arrays within the array and change text formats in parse to integers and floats. My current code looks as follows:

```
require 'CSV'

parse = CSV.read("testDB.csv")
parse.map do |code, cat, pervol, percnt, rate, fee| 
  code.to_i
  pervol.to_f
  percnt.to_i
  rate.to_f
  fee.to_f
end
```

I am new to ruby and know this is incorrect but I am having trouble finding the right combination to change the arrays accordingly. can anyone assist with a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to do this?:

```
parse.map{ |r| [r[0].to_i, r[1], r[2].to_f, r[3].to_f, r[4].to_f, r[5].to_f] }
#=> [[742, "Rewards", 0.309, 0.249, 0.0195, 0.1], [742, "Reg (DB)", 0.165, 0.194, 0.0005, 0.21]]
```

`parse` is an array of array, so, in `map` you will have to access array object with its index and then do your operations accordingly.

As Jörg W Mittag pointed out, you can do this with destructuring bind and meaningful variable names(which helps in understanding which object is what in the array) like this:

```
parse.map{ |code, cat, pervol, percnt, rate, fee| [code.to_i, cat, pervol.to_f, percnt.to_f, rate.to_f, fee.to_f] }
```

Comment: ah thank you, i was missing the array brackets when attempting it this way before, i see now. thank you!

Comment: This would be much easier to read if you used destructuring bind and meaningful variable names instead of meaningless indices: `parse.map{ |code, cat, pervol, percnt, rate, fee| [code.to_i, cat, pervol.to_f, percnt.to_f, rate.to_f, fee.to_f] }`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following:

```
parse = [["742", "Rewards",  "0.309", "0.249", "0.0195", "0.1"],
         ["742", "Reg (23)", "0.165", "0.194", "0.0005", "0.21"]]

parse.map do |arr|
  arr.map do |e|
    case e
    when /^\d+$/ then e.to_i
    when /^\d+\.\d+$/ then e.to_f
    else e
    end
  end
end
  #=> [[742, "Rewards", 0.309, 0.249, 0.0195, 0.1],
  #    [742, "Reg (23)", 0.165, 0.194, 0.0005, 0.21]]
```